# For FTP and HTTP free space size

Tags: java

I want to know the free space on http and ftp path(network path like `http://aboiil/hello` and FTP) using java. I found a sample to know the free space on local drive:

```
System.out.println(new File("\\\\altiris-vss\\SYM-SMP").getFreeSpace());
```

Please help me i am unable to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to solve this on the client side of communicating with a FTP or HTTP server. The server side running these services would have to provide a mechanism to query for the free space.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a standard way to determine how much data you can upload to a HTTP server. It will depend on your HTTP server how you do this.

FTP doesn't have a standard way to get free space.